# I can't understand what's going wrong with my css

Tags: javascript, html, css, rotation, css-transforms

I am a beginner to web development.

I am not able to understand...

Why It (#circle) Element goes down
When I add (transform: rotate(0deg);) to (#circle)?

because as far as I know (transform: rotate(0deg);) does'nt affect position.

What Should I do?

I've given full code Here and in this Hyperlink also....

[Full code](https://jsfiddle.net/seaf1d47)

```js
var circle = document.getElementById("circle")
var upbtn = document.getElementById("upbtn")
var downbtn = document.getElementById("doenbtn")

var rotateValue = circle.style.transform;
var rotateSum;

upbtn.onclick = function()
{
    rotateSum = rotateValue + "rotate(-90deg)";
    circle.style.transform = rotateSum;
    rotateValue = rotateSum;
}
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
body{
    font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
    background: linear-gradient(to right, #9c27b0, #8ecdff);
    color: #fff;
}

.logo{
    display: inline-block;
    flex-basis: 20%;
    z-index: 1;
}
.logo img{
    width: 13vw;
    margin-left: 1vw;
    margin-top: 1vw;
}
nav{
    position: sticky;
}
.navbar{
    float: right;
}
.navbar ul{
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
}
.navbar ul li{
    margin-top: 1.8vw;
    margin-right: 3vw;
}
.navbar ul li a{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
.info{
    z-index: -1;
    width: 60vw;
    height: 140vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    /* left: -10%; */
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
#circle{
    width: 60vw;
    height: 140vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    border-radius: 50%;
    transform: rotate(0deg);
    transition: all 1s;
    /* background-color: #000 ; */
}
.feature img{
    width: 70px;
}
.feature{
    position: absolute;
    display: flex;
    color: #fff;
}
.feature div{
    margin-left: 30px;
}
.feature div p{
    margin-top: 8px;
}
#f1{
    top: 470px;
    right: 50px;
}
#f2{
    top: 200px;
    left: 350px;
}
#f3{
    bottom: 430px;
    left: 50px;
}
#f4{
    bottom: 170px;
    right: 300px;
}

.mobile{
    width: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 35%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 2;
}
.controls{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 10%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    text-align: center;
}
.controls h3{
    margin: 15px 0;
    color: #fff;
}
#upbtn{
    width: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#downbtn{
    width: 15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <title>Real Phone</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
        <nav>
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="images/resourses/logo.png" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Phones</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Accessories</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cart</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        </nav> 
        <div class="info">
            <img src="/images/resourses/mobile.png" alt="" class="mobile">
            <div id="circle">
                <div class="feature" id="f1">
                    <h1>¯\_(ツ)_/¯</h1>
                    <!-- <img src="/images/resourses/camera.png" alt=""> -->
                    <div>
                        <h1>Camera</h1>
                        <p>32MP, Wide Angle Lens</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature" id="f2">
                    <h1>¯\_(ツ)_/¯</h1>
                    <!-- <img src="/images/resourses/processor.png" alt=""> -->
                    <div>
                        <h1>Processor</h1>
                        <p>Snapdragon Octa-core 11nm</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature" id="f3">
                    <h1>¯\_(ツ)_/¯</h1>
                    <!-- <img src="/images/resourses/display.png" alt=""> -->
                    <div>
                        <h1>Display</h1>
                        <p>6.5" Mini-Drop Fullscreen</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="feature" id="f4">
                    <h1>¯\_(ツ)_/¯</h1>
                    <!-- <img src="/images/resourses/battery.png" alt=""> -->
                    <div>
                        <h1>Bettery Life</h1>
                        <p>5000mAh, 720hrs Standby</p>
                    </div>
                </div> 
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="controls">
            <h1 id="upbtn">^</h1>
            <!-- <img src="/images/resourses/arrow.png" alt="" id="upbtn"> -->
            <h3>Features</h3>
            <!-- <img src="/images/resourses/arrow.png" alt="" id="downbtn"> -->
            <h1 id="downbtn">^</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is not the correct way to add multiple transform styles.

```
#circle {
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: rotate(0deg);
}
```

The correct way is to add Transform with multiple values is this:

```
#circle {
   transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(0deg);
}
```

Comment: If I do that then the div gets the correct position but when I click on (upbtn) then It goes to same position (at bottom)  You can check on your own or go to this link (https://jsfiddle.net/p6kmvr7e/)

Comment: The reasons behind it go back to its old position is your javascript. Please update this javascript line: rotateSum = rotateValue + "translateY(-50%) rotate(-90deg)";

Comment: If you want to rotate this to 90deg, then change the values of properties.

Comment: I am a very absolute beginner I cant under stand what u r saying

Comment: please explain it with details.............!!!

Comment: Hi sorry man i was not Stackoverflow for a while. But I can assist you now. You want all the items rotate on center of the page right? https://jmp.sh/L3Kggl7

Comment: No problem but problem is solved now.........!

Comment: I've given (top: 50%) to (#circle) not necessarily.......

Comment: I've given (top: 50%) to (#circle) not necessarily.......